# Generate CSV from text files with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I want to generate a CSV file with columns `name`, `foo` and `bar`. It could look like this:

```
name,foo,bar
a.txt,yes,no
b.txt,no,yes
c.txt,no,no
```

The CSV file would be created when I iterate over a directory with text files and interpret its contents.

a.txt has the following content:

```
foo:yes
bar:no
baz:?
```

b.txt has the following content:

```
foo:no
bar:yes
```

c.txt has the following content:

```
foo
bar:no
baz:yes
```

There shouldn't be a `baz` column. Just the specified `foo` and `bar`. It is also possible that either key-value-pair is missing or incomplete (like in c.txt). Then there should be `no` as value.

I'm sure that it is possible with `awk` or `sed`, but have no idea how to implement it. Something like:

`find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c "awk '...' {}"`

Comment: What if you want to print a column for key "bob" but "bob" isn't present any input file - should you still print the "bob" column with all "no" values or not print that column at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to print the column for each target key even if one or more of those target keys is not present in any input file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numKeys = split("foo bar", tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        keys[i] = tmp[i]
    }
    FS=":"; OFS=","
}
{ fnameKey2val[FILENAME,$1] = $2 }
END {
    printf "%s%s", "name", OFS
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s%s", key, (keyNr<numKeys ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for (fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGC; fileNr++) {
        fname = ARGV[fileNr]
        printf "%s%s", fname, OFS
        for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
            key = keys[keyNr]
            val = (fnameKey2val[fname,key] == "" ? "no" : fnameKey2val[fname,key])
            printf "%s%s", val, (keyNr<numKeys ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

or if you do NOT want to print a column for a key if it's missing from all files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("foo bar", tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        targets[tmp[i]]
    }
    FS=":"; OFS=","
}
!($1 in targets) { next }
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
{ fnameKey2val[FILENAME,$1] = $2 }
END {
    printf "%s%s", "name", OFS
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s%s", key, (keyNr<numKeys ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for (fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGC; fileNr++) {
        fname = ARGV[fileNr]
        printf "%s%s", fname, OFS
        for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
            key = keys[keyNr]
            val = (fnameKey2val[fname,key] == "" ? "no" : fnameKey2val[fname,key])
            printf "%s%s", val, (keyNr<numKeys ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

They'll both produce the same output from the given sample input:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk *.txt
name,foo,bar
a.txt,yes,no
b.txt,no,yes
c.txt,no,no
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` approach would be:

```
gawk -F':' -v OFS=',' '
BEGIN{ print "name", "foo", "bar"; };
    $2== ""    { $2="no"; };
    $1== "foo" { hold[FILENAME][1]= $2; };
    $1== "bar" { hold[FILENAME][2]= $2; };
END{ for (x in hold) print x, hold[x][1], hold[x][2]; }
' [abc].txt
```

---

Output:

```
name,foo,bar
c.txt,no,no
a.txt,yes,no
b.txt,no,yes
```

Answer (score 0):

perl method:

```
perl -lne '
  BEGIN {
    @A = qw(foo bar);
    @{$h{$_}}{@A} = qw(no) x @A for @ARGV;
  }
  /^(foo|bar)(:.*|$)/ and 
    ($h{$ARGV}{$1} = length($2)<2?"no":$2) =~ s/^://;
  }{$,=",";
  print q(name), @A;
  print $_, @{$h{$_}}{@A} for sort keys %h;
' -- *.txt
name,foo,bar
a.txt,yes,no
b.txt,no,yes
c.txt,no,no
```

---

Another method using grep-sort-sed pipelines and assuming foo/bar exist in the file

```
echo 'name,foo, bar'
grep -HE '^(foo|bar)(:|$)' *.txt |
sed -e '/:.*:/!s/$/:no/' |
sort -t: -k1,1 -k2,2r |
sed -Ee 'N;s/\n[^:]+:/:/;y/:/,/' |
cut -d, -f1,3,5
```